# Can't see changes in Vue.JS dev server until I Git Push/Pull using VS Code

Tags: git, vue.js, github, visual-studio-code

I'm having this recurring issue where if I fall too far behind master, the push/pull process in Git no longer collects all of the changes made.

The following things happen:

- VS Code doesn't collect all of the remote changes in a pull consistently
- VS Code stops consistently tracking changes in files, so they don't show up under the Source Control tab as changed in order to be pushed
- Changes made locally to files stop reflecting in the `npm run serve` local dev server
- In order to see a change to a file, I need to push it to GitHub and then pull it, which means I can't work locally effectively

I've tried:

- `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git fetch --all`
- Switching branches and then `git rebase master`
- Restarting npm server, computer, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That´s a strange behavior. When you say terminal, do you mean the VS Code terminal, or the system terminal? Also, what operating system are you working on? Linux, Windows, macOS? Have you checked that the path that is opened in VS Code is the same as in the terminal? It would be great if you add all this info to the question.  It will increase the chances of somebody answering it.

Comment: macOS, and using the system terminal. It's the same path.